# Distinct SQL Join two tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two tables such that I am getting only a first match from the Right table instead of every match in Table2.

So if the query is:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Dates
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2 = ID
WHERE T1.Name = 'John'
```

I would like to see

```
John | 14/11/14
Joe  | 10/10/2014
Jane | 25/10/2014
```

Instead of

```
John | 14/11/2014    
John | 12/10/2014
Joe  | 10/10/2014
Jane | 25/10/2014
Jane | 26/10/2014
```

Which join should I use?[image]

Comment: Thats not a distinct value, you could achieve a specific date by using a min or a max function?

Comment: `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`? You've got two id=1 records in table 2,s o you're going to get two records in the overall result set.

Comment: USE INNER JOIN, use TOP 1

Comment: I guess I wasn't too specific, I want to be able to remove the `WHERE T1.Name = 'John'` and get a list of all Names (one of each) and only the first date from the Table2

Comment: How could it be possible to get the names `Joe` and `Jane` if you have `WHERE        T1.name='John' ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide which row, you should select. Min or max as commented.

```
SELECT T1.Name,
( SELECT MIN( T2.Dates) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2 = ID) AS Dates
FROM Table1 T1 
WHERE T1.Name = 'John'
```

Comment: Updated the initial question as I would need to drop the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI standard function `row_number()` can be a big help here.  It is supported by most databases, so you can do:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Dates
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY t2.DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Table2 t2
     ) T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND seqnum = 1
WHERE T1.Name = 'John';
```

In your question, you have only one column from the second table, so you can also do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, MAX(t2.Date)
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE T1.Name = 'John'
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Query**

```
SELECT a.name,
MAX(b.Dates)
FROM tbl1 a
JOIN tbl2 b
ON a.id=b.id
WHERE a.name='John'
GROUP BY a.name;
```

### **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40c1e0/1)**